How to enable auto-complete in drop down menu's for HTML/React tags(IntelliJ IDEA) without using '<' or Tab key
I recently decided to shift all development work including TSX work to Intellij. However one issue is that whenever I start to type a tag such as div.. or butto... or Carouse... I dont get any autocomplete suggestion at all.
I have to put a '<' symbol before I write my tag to get suggestions as shown below

I'd like this exact functionality but without having to type '<' character
Another user on StackOverflow had the exact query and had to resort to this method-
1)Enter full name of the tag/ React component
2)Press tab, which causes Emmet to surround with <>
However, I'd ideally like to write the tag directly without putting a '<' or writing the entire React Component name(which can be very lengthy) and press Tab.
What I want-

Starting typing di..(div) or Carous...(Carousel)
IDEA shows me drop down suggestion to insert the full  or  tag

